# Sorting an organizations repositories by forkCount using Github GraphQL endpoint

Tags: graphql

I am new to GraphQL, trying to learn - so far so good, but I have hit my first issue.

Using the GraphQL playground, I am able to select repositories for an organization:

```
{
  organization(login: "github") {
    name
    repositories(first:10) {
      nodes {
        name,
        forkCount        
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

I get results successfully - What I cannot figure out is how to sort by `forkCount` (preferably `DESC`)

I've tried a bunch of stuff, mostly helped by the tool's autocomplete, I was able to  sort by another property, `STARGAZERS`, but that's not my aim here.

```
{
  organization(login: "github") {
    name
    repositories(first: 10, orderBy: { field: STARGAZERS direction: DESC }) {
      nodes {
        name
        forkCount
        forks {
          totalCount
        }
        stargazers {
          totalCount
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I sort by `forkCount`?